# Does my master server crash using Log-Shipping Synchronous Replication in Postgresql when the replica is down?

Tags: postgresql, replication, synchronous, high-availability, log-shipping

I'm searching for HA solutions without load balancing in the master-slave model, using postgresql. My favorite solution so far is log shipping synchronous replication. But I have one main concern, and that is, if my slave server becomes unavailable, will my master server continue it's operation? Or will it wait for the acknowledgment of my slave server until it's up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one standby, the master will halt ( by design ).

The master will still serve read-only statements, but all writes will be blocked until the standby comes back.

You can avoid this scenario by providing multiple candidates in `synchronous_standby_names`.

See [SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION) in the PostgreSQL Docs.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear! Because I only have 2 servers. so I guess that the best solution for me is to use asynchronous streaming log shipping. Or is there a better way?

Comment: You always can add pg_receivexlog/pg_receivewal as an syncrhonous standby, so you can make sure that: all wals are backed up on a crash and the master runs without a "real" standby

Comment: I didn't get your sayings... can you explain a bit more?

Comment: If you want to use synchronous replication with only two nodes, you can use the tool `pg_recivewal` ( or `pg_recivexlog` in older versions ) as a synchronous standby. See the linked documentation how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to prevent the master halt at slave crash. We can use `wal_sender_timeout` in masters `postgresql.conf` file to disconnect from the slave if it's been crashed.